# Using html5 in magento

Tags: html, validation, magento

Trying to validate html5 and I get following errors:

```
Error: Saw < when expecting an attribute name. Probable cause: Missing > immediately before.
At line 3, column 1
html lang="nl"↩<head>↩<meta ht
Warning: Attribute <head is not serializable as XML 1.0.
From line 1, column 16; to line 3, column 6
TYPE HTML>↩<html lang="nl"↩<head>↩<meta

Error: Attribute <head not allowed on element html at this point.
From line 1, column 16; to line 3, column 6
TYPE HTML>↩<html lang="nl"↩<head>↩<meta
Attributes for element html:
Global attributes
```

manifest

Answer (score 1):

Magento's default (and most of the third party) themes don't validate to the HTML5 specification. The default ones were created around 2007/2008 before HTML5 was mainstream.  Check with individual theme authors for the 3rd party ones if you want HTML5 support.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Boilerplate is an open source project you should look at. It may not be 100% to the spec, but it looks like your best bet.

https://github.com/zeljkoprsa/Magento-Boilerplate